# Convert scalar from sif to hrf

Tags: format, stata, scalar

I am looping over a set of scalars which contain quarterly sif values. I would like to convert them to hrf format and keep them stored in scalars.

However, I found that `format %tq` only accepts variables. Hence, the only workaround seems to i) convert the scalar to a variable ii) apply `format %tq` iii) convert the variable to a scalar.

Is there a more elegant and faster way to do this? (I am using Stata MP 15.1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have string scalars, so you can do this. I can't see why it would be useful, but that could be failure of imagination; you could enlighten us on why you want this.

```
. scalar foo = yq(2018, 4)

. scalar foo = string(scalar(foo), "%tq")

. scalar list
       foo = 2018q4
```

What is quite different for scalars is that there is no sense whatsoever in which a display format is attached to or associated with a scalar. You can hold a numeric date or a string date in a scalar, but those are the only choices. You can't have a numeric value with a format on the side that Stata will use for display when suitable. You found that out when you attempted to `format` a scalar.

Goodness knows whether this is faster (than what?) or more elegant (who decides?). The major difference is that a variable manifestly can contain many dates and a changed format made just once with `format` can apply to them consistently, whereas changing how you show a bunch of scalars requires a loop every time you do it so far as I can see. Further, it follows from above that you might need to keep two sets of scalars, one numeric for calculation and one string for display.

I've used date constants and typically found that either I use them directly (subtracting 2000 as base doesn't requiring putting it into anything) or I use local macros to hold them. But I can't see anything wrong with using scalars, except possibly indirection.